# How to close the question that you had answer already?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [Windows 10 Creator Update Version 1703](https://superuser.com/questions/1249534/windows-10-creator-update-version-1703)

I have get the answer i was expected so how can i close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To indicate that a question is resolved, you can click the check mark next to an answer to accept it. You've already done the right thing. For more information on what to do when someone answers your question, see the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

We prefer that solved questions are left in existence so that they can help future searchers. Note that on Stack Exchange, questions still can receive new answers even after one is accepted - this is in case someone comes in later with an even better solution. Questions are only closed when they are duplicates or do not adhere to our guidelines for good questions. Even if a question is marked ("closed") as a duplicate, it can still be helpful in pointing more search terms at the canonical version, so you don't need to take any further action.

Comment: okay i get it. thank you!